# Sliding menu listeners

Tags: android, menu, listener, slidingmenu

In this program I have implemented the [sliding library](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu). Implement this library, I am trying to create a *MenuActivity* class that processes all the menu item slider options, onClick listeners, etc. For now the class looks like this:

```
public class MenuActivity extends SlidingActivity{

    SharePrefManager sm = new SharePrefManager(MenuActivity.this);
    RelativeLayout ask_a_question, life_prediction;
    TextView aries,taurus,gemini,cancer,leo,virgo,libra,scorpio,sagittarius,capricon,aquarius,pisces;
    String isLoggedIn; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu);

        ask_a_question = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.ask_a_question);

        HashMap<String, String> checkLogin = new HashMap<String, String>();
        checkLogin = sm.getuserDetails();
        isLoggedIn = checkLogin.get(SharePrefManager.KEY_ISLOGEDIN);

        ask_a_question.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (isLoggedIn.equals(0))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You must be logged in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                else
                {
                    Intent i = new Intent("com.example.btshome.ASKPAGE");
                    startActivity(i);
                }

            }
        });


    }


}
```

This class is basically implementing the library and setting up the sliding menu items and the onClick event handlers. This class is also accessing the Preferences, so as to check if the user is logged in.

On my *MainActivity* class I am extending this class and trying to get the functionality out of it.

```
public class MainActivity extends MenuActivity{

    Button login;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.log_in_button);
        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent("com.example.btshome.LOGINACTIVITY"));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

On the following implementation the following error is occurring:

```
04-24 10:46:45.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1956): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-24 10:46:45.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1956): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.btshome/com.example.btshome.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-24 10:46:45.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1956):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
04-24 10:46:45.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1956):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
04-24 10:46:45.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1956):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
04-24 10:46:45.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1956):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
04-24 10:46:45.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1956):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-24 10:46:45.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1956):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-24 10:46:45.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1956):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
04-24 10:46:45.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1956):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-24 10:46:45.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1956):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-24 10:46:45.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1956):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
04-24 10:46:45.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1956):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-24 10:46:45.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1956):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-24 10:46:45.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1956): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-24 10:46:45.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1956):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:153)
04-24 10:46:45.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1956):     at com.example.btshome.library.SharePrefManager.<init>(SharePrefManager.java:35)
04-24 10:46:45.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1956):     at com.example.btshome.MenuActivity.<init>(MenuActivity.java:17)
04-24 10:46:45.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1956):     at com.example.btshome.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:14)
04-24 10:46:45.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1956):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
04-24 10:46:45.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1956):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
04-24 10:46:45.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1956):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
04-24 10:46:45.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1956):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
04-24 10:46:45.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1956):     ... 11 more
```

So what is going wrong here ?? Is it the *MenuActivity* class? Do I approach this problem in a different way??

Comment: It's in the initialization of your `SharePrefManager`, specifically `SharePrefManager.java:35`. Likely a `ContextWrapper` initialized with `null` context.